# Rails override default scope global

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, default-scope

I have a Rails 3.2 application, and I want to use one database for many clients and one application. So for every model I have created a field called `account_id`, now I want to add a global scope for filtering the row in the base of the `account_id` of the logging user(`account_id` is a session param). So in initialize I have created a file and put these code

```
module ActiveRecord
  # = Active Record Named \Scopes                                                                                                                                                                                 \

  module Scoping
    module Default
      module ClassMethods

        def unscoped #:nodoc:                                                                                                                                                         
            return  (block_given? ? relation.scoping { yield } : relation).where(account_id: Thread.current['account_id'].id)

    end

        def default_scope(scope = {})
          scope = Proc.new if block_given?
          if scope.kind_of?(Array) || scope.is_a?(Hash)
              scope.merge!({:conditions=>{account_id:Thread.current['account_id'].id}})
            end
            self.default_scopes = default_scopes + [scope]
          end
        end
   end
  end
end
```

If I logged with user `account_id=2` all is ok, but if in the same moment I logged on another browser or computer with `account_id=3` ...I have many errors and on the log, I have seen that the application use `account_id=2` but also `account_id=3` at the same time.

Any solution? How I can rewrite `default_scope(scope = {})`? Other other idea?

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.current[]` data is not unique per request. I used to have the same problem.  By that time I had been using this gem https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store. Hope it will help or at least give an idea.